# AngularJS - HTTP POST Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to do a simple HTTP post in my `Jasmine` test using `Karma`. I have the code and it works because I use the Chrome app `Postman` and have successfully retrieved user credentials.

So it must be my `unit test`. What am I doing wrong?

**signInSpec.js**:

```
describe('Service: AuthFactory',function(){

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('ui.router');
        module('users');
    });

    var AuthFactory, httpBackend;

    beforeEach(function($httpBackend, _AuthFactory_) {
        httpBackend = $httpBackend;
        AuthFactory = _AuthFactory_;
    });

    it('should return POST', function(done) {
        AuthFactory.signIn({inputType: {user: "admin"}, credInput: {password: "pass123"}});

    httpBackend.when('POST','http://localhost:3000/api/AuthFactoryServ/signIn')
        .respond (200, {});

    httpBackend.flush(); // to return the response
    }, 20000);

});
```

and **AuthFactory.js**:

```
angular.module('users').factory('AuthFactory', ['$http', function($http) {

    var AuthFactory = {};

    AuthFactory.signIn = function(data) {
        return $http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/AuthFactoryServ/signIn', data);
    };

    AuthFactory.signOut = function(data) {
        return $http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/AuthFactoryServ/signOut', data);
    };

    return AuthFactory;

}]);
```

And the error:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0) Service: Authentication should return POST F
AILED
        Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specifi
ed by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'AuthFactory.signIn')
            at C:/maink/client/tests/signInSpec.js:1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mock the actual ajax call so it will call your fake

```
it('should return POST', function(done) {
     // dont worry about calls to assets
     httpBackend.when ('POST','http://localhost:3000/api/AuthFactoryServ/signIn')
              .respond (200, {});

    AuthFactory.signIn({inputType: {user: "admin"}, credInput: {password: "pass123"}});
    httpBackend.flush(); // to return the response
```

Comment: don't forget to flush the calls too

Comment: @maurycy I added the flush

Comment: Cool, now only the `AuthFactory.signIn()` has to before flush and OP is all set ;)

Comment: @HenryZou Oh right! I forgot about that. I tried it this way but I am still getting `Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.` :|

Comment: put the mock before the actual api call.

Comment: I updated my code to show the order of mock/api-call

Comment: `AuthFactory.signIn()` is the one that `creates` the http call, it needs to be placed before `httpBackend.flush()`